# How delete row (friendsWithMe-friend_user_id) from join table (ManyToMany self-referencing) Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, self-reference

I would like to make "Friends" like on FB in Symfony2-Doctrine2.

I am using http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

I want, a User can remove friend from his friend list if his friend is myFriend or friendWithMe.

On this case ManyToMany Self-referencing only I can remove myFriend.

**How can I remove friendWithMe?**